# bootstrap modal popup does not show at all

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

i'm new to bootstrap and i can't seem to get my modal working. my data-target="#details-1". what could be the problem.i have tried to find it for several days to no avail. thanks in advance.here's the code

```
        <!--header tags-->
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>m-kibanda</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-grid.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexboxgrid.css">
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
          user-scalable=no">
          <script 
         src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
         </script>
          <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        </head>
        <!--my modal-->
        <div class="modal fade details-1" id="details-1" tabindex="-1" 
        role="dialog" aria-labelledby="details-1" aria-hidden="true">
           <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
             <div class="modal-header">
               <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-
        label="Close">
                 <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
               </button>
              <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Cabbages</h4>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-body">
               <div class="container-fluid">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                     <div class="center-block">
                       <img src="images/New Folder/JPEG/11.jpg" alt="Cabbages" 
        class="details img-responsive">
                     </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were missing the following attributes `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#details-1"`. These are bootstrap specific and tell the bootstrap.js scripts to open a modal / which element to target.

```css
.img-responsive {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#details-1"> Details</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="details-1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Cabbages</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
               <div class="center-block text-center">
                 <img src="http://www.rivieraproduce.eu/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/image_riviera_savoy_cabbage.jpg" alt="Cabbages" 
  class="details img-responsive">
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
           </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so sorry i forgot to include the button in my question. i had it              
  
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#details-1">
                Details</button>

Comment: I updated the example with your button markup given in the comment above. Does the above solution answer your question?

Comment: it actually does respond!thank you loads. i just used your head tags and the code responded. guess something was wrong with my head tags

Comment: now the problem is everytime i reload the page the modal appears even without clicking the modal button..any suggestions?

Comment: Those are cdn (web hosted) links for the external libraries. Most likely in your example you are referencing bootstrap etc in the wrong location. Check where bootstrap.js is stored on your pc and compare it with where you are telling your site to find it

Comment: Sorry I meant bootstrap.min.css in comment above.

Comment: @Elvis there must be some external js firing in your site somewhere. Can you post your full code? Or create a codepen? It's hard to tell as the example i gave above won't do that without some external code forcing it to

Comment: Yonda, it was just a stupid mistake. found the javascript code.thanks and cheers!

Comment: @Elvis Mawira great. If my solution helped you can mark it as accepted. Otherwise don't worry about it :)

Answer (score 0):

Place the jquery call at first, and you have to trigger the show up of your modal by any click event.

```
$('#details-1').modal('show')
```

Comment: thanks @zakaria, i have added the line but still nothing! I'm thinking of going with another method of displaying my pop-up now